# Updated GAE to 1.8.6 - what do I do now

Tags: google-app-engine, go

My installation of GAE told me I should upgrade.

I downloaded the zip - renamed the old folder called *go_appengine* to *go_appengine-1.8.5* and extracted a brand new *go_appengine* folder from the zip.

Now when I try to build under LiteIde I get the massage:

```
go build runtime: windows/386 must be bootstrapped using make.bash
```

and when I try to run my app I get:

```
Failed to build Go application: C:\Go\GAE\go_appengine\google\src\...go can't find import: "math/big"
```

I am sure there is a simple command I need to execute to build everything but I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are aware of the problem (our goof, basically), and are in the process of building a new Go SDK for Windows.

Updated: If you're on Windows, you'll want to replace the 1.8.6 SDK with 1.8.6.1. It's up on the download site now.

Comment: Thanks Dave - Could you post here when it's fixed?

Comment: I'll update this as soon as I know when the new SDK lands. (It might appear while I'm asleep.)

Comment: The new SDK is on the project's download page now: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/list

Comment: Yup. 1.8.6.1 is what you want for Windows.

Comment: That fixed  the "can't find import" issue but I still get the LiteIde message. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Had a problem similar to the second error message, except it couldn't find "fmt" or any of the standard packages when I ran dev_appserver.py

At some point I tried renaming the **goroot\pkg\windows_amd64_appengine** dir to **goroot\pkg\windows_amd64** like it was called in the 1.8.3

and boom! it worked for some reason, though dev_appserver keeps passing the old dir name to go-app-builder

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a package it is usually because it is not on your local system or not where Go expects to find it. It looks like you're using windows, and I'm not completely familiar with windows as a development environment, but your file structure looks like it may be confusing the compiler.

I can say that the Go compiler will be looking for `math/big` in the directory`GOROOT/src/pkg/math/big` where GOROOT is the location that Go runs from. So if it can't find the package, then `src/pkg/math/big` is not a subdirectory of the directory that Go is running from, which means you either have Go running from a bad location or the directories got messed up somehow.

Again, I'm not very familiar with windows, but from a linux terminal you can figure out where the GOROOT is using `$echo $GOROOT` or `$which go`. There may be some equivalent way of finding the directory your compiler is running from and then you can try and trace down the directory from there.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - I am indeed working in Windows <spit>. I replaced the old folder with the new one in exactly the same place with exactly the same name. My logic suggests that this should be a seamless replacement.

Comment: Looking at the folder structure in the 1.8.6 zip file, matching the unzipped "go_appengine" with your directory, it seems to dead-end at /go_appengine/google/. Meaning there is no /go_appengine/google/src, but there is a "/go_appengine/goroot/src/pkg/math/big" so it is possible they may have changed the file structure in this release.

Comment: I think the `src` folder was created by LiteIde. I moved that over into the new folder to get my projects back but the project build fails with the noted error. I haven't changed any environment variables. GOROOT is still set to *GOROOT=C:\Go\GAE\go_appengine\goroot\*.

Comment: I've renamed in my old folder - moved my *src* folder back and everything is running again. Happy for any suggestions going forward.